# BLE in python script in termux

Tags: python, android, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, termux

I'm writing my bachelor thesis and I've successfully compiled a script in python which uses BLE to gather data from an Arduino nano 33 IoT. I now wish to run this python script on termux on my android phone: here comes the trouble! My professor warned me about some problems that might occur trying to use BLE on Android.

An example from the Bleak library using BLE is the following:

```
    import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

asyncio.run(main())
```

but I get this error on termux:

```
python scanBLE.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/python/scanBLE.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bleak import BleakScanner
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bleak/init.py", line 41, in <module>
    if not _on_ci and not check_bluez_version(5, 43):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/init.py", line 17, in check_bluez_version
    p = subprocess.Popen(["bluetoothctl", "--version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in init
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1840, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bluetoothctl'
```

Please don't tell me that I have to root my phone! So my question is: *Is there a way to give access to the BLE from a python code running in termux ?*

Comment: See: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1232

Comment: I don't have to activate it, I need to run a script that uses BLE.

Comment: From: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1232#issuecomment-526578317 `we don't have a bluetooth API so no.`